# Dynamically increase size of asyncio.Queue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Is it possible to dynamically change (increase) max size of `asyncio.Queue` object when there are already items in the queue?

What side effects are expected if it is done by manipulating internal properties?

Comment: To investigate what could happen if you mess with the internals, the source code is free for you to look at.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you feel you need to resize a queue? Maybe there is a better approach to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible. There is no method of `asyncio.Queue` to do this.

To get a queue with a different size you need to create a new one and possibly transfer all items, or you could for example create a setup where you can alternate between two queues, allowing you to replace the one that is currently not in use.

---

If you decide to manipulate the internal state of the queue that is not accessible through its interface, you might get it to work now, but you can not rely on it to not break when there are any Python updates.

Comment: I would consider a third possibility: copy the `asyncio.Queue` [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/queues.py) (which only uses the public asyncio API) into your project and modify it as needed. That way its state is no longer internal - it belongs to the Queue fork that you control - and you can be sure that it won't break in future releases. The downside is that you don't automatically get bugfixes and improvements to `Queue` in future releases, but the implementation is very mature, so this is not a problem in practice.